# Change scrollbar value while scrolling even if the Focus is on a different object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, focus, scrollbar

I have a textBox and a vScrollBar on a Form. I'd like the textBox to have focus, but when it does, using the Scroll button on the mouse won't change the scrollbar value. If the scrollbar has the focus, I can easily scroll with the mouse, but typing text in the textbox won't work then. Is there any way to catch all the scroll button activity on the form and redirect it to the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle MouseWheel event of TextBox...

```
public frmSTOverScrollText()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtInput.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(txtInput_MouseWheel);
}

void txtInput_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        if (vsInput.Value + vsInput.LargeChange <= vsInput.Maximum)
            vsInput.Value += vsInput.LargeChange;
    }
    else if (vsInput.Value - vsInput.LargeChange >= vsInput.Minimum)
        vsInput.Value -= vsInput.LargeChange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go under the forms properties and add a KeyDown event, inside the event type:

```
yourTextBox.Text += e.KeyValue;
```

After that, go under the textbox properties and add an Enter event, inside the event type:

```
this.Focus();
```

Essentially what will happen is this. The form will now direct each keypress to the textbox. When the textbox is in focus, said textbox will unfocus itself letting the form append any characters to the textbox.

Comment: Yes I thought of that, and this would work for sure, but I'd rather like a solution where the Focus is really on the textbox, and the scroll gets redirected, because the user won't start typing text, until he's sure that the textbox has the focus. Besides, editing text would be harder, too. But thank you for the idea.